# How to fix HDD is not detecting?

Tags: hard-drive

I've 500 GB HDD which is not detecting, at startup it says :

```
print_req_Error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 8089735   
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 4044866, async page read    
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 4044867, async page read
```

Also HDD making clicking sound.

I tried clean HDD pcb pins which were so much dirty.
And also checked changing SATA cable and in with other ports but it doesn't worked.

So how can I fix this issue?

Comment: If it's clicking, it's dead. Buy a new one & copy back from your backup.

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/550840/buffer-i-o-errors
Hope that this may help you in Understanding & correcting the error.

Comment: It's internal HDD + is not detecting to check it using some tools like fsck.

Comment: There is no big difference in logical architecture of internal or extrenal hard drives, the problem is the HDD shows error in **Buffer I/O read**,
As you stated the hard disk according me is dead for sure, cause clicking sound states that the pointer head is unable to read the sectors.
Better buy new one.

Comment: @hemlata this is bad advice. Doing this seriously risks compounding issues on a seriously failing drive. Sending it to recovery experts (if highly valuable) or attempting something like ddrescue to pull data off it at a block level (which you clean up with fsck from the copy) are more prudent suggestions.